# exporting a collection to re import into blender?

Tags: import

Hi I am trying to re import a layer/collection back to a newer blender file. I noticed that I can not export as blender. I managed to export my collection as FBX, but all the modifiers got applied.

What I am trying to do is to import a layer into a blender newer file (with all the modifiers).

Is this possible ? Thanks

Bruno

Answer (score 1):

You can append collections from an existing Blender project to another/new project by using *File > Append*. Select the .blend file that contains the collection that you want to append and open the *Collection* directory inside the file. Select the collections and click *Append from Library*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just select collection with everything inside, copy it and paste to new project